# Apply a data-rule format to the request-parameters dataset?

Tags: dataset, aviarc

Is there a way to apply a data-rule to the request-parameters dataset?.

I'm trying to format a field as a date using a data-rule but it gives me a no-current-row error on the request-parameters dataset.

If not i'll just use a new dataset.

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datarules can not be applied to the dataset post-creation unless you use custom XML command for that.

The engine v 3.6.2 which is about to be released suppose to support binding datasets to data rules post-creation.

Regards,
Vlad

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I'll use another dataset